# Axios seemingly manipulates passed data

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, nuxt.js

#### My current NuxtJS Application contains the following code:

```js
  // Create a new Canvas-Object on a Whiteboard
  async createCanvasObject({ state }, canvasObject) {
    if (!state.id) {
      console.error(' Canvas ID is not defined!');
      return;
    }
    console.log(canvasObject);
    console.log(canvasObject.mtiID);
    await this.$axios
      .$post(`/whiteboard/${state.id}/canvas/object`, {
        object: canvasObject,
      })
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
  },
```

#### What should this code do?

It *should* send a passed object `canvasObject` via POST-Request to my backend, without modifying it.
The canvasObject itself is a JSON-Object, which describes an Object on a Canvas.

The logging directly before the Axios-Call yields something like this:
[image]

As you can see, there is a lot of stuff defined, and espacially the attribute `mtiID`.

#### Now the Problem:

If we look at the request, we can see, that a lot of stuff got stripped away from my JSON, including the `mtiID`. I have no idea why. The only 'Middleware', that is currently applied to Axios just logs every request to the console, without modifying it.

[image]

Comment: Axios doesn't have a `$post` method.

Comment: It does in NuxtJS https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage/.
But the problem also persists, while using the normal post-Method

Comment: `canvasObject` is not a simple object. It has getters and setters defined. Does it have a `toJSON` property?

Comment: Yep, I just figured it out. It actually is caused by the custom toJSON(), which I did miss. I somehow was in the belief, that I'm dealing with a simple JSON-Object..